# How to search MKMapView's annotation with UISearchBar?

Tags: objective-c, annotations, mapkit, uisearchbar

I'm designing objective c application using MKMapView kit that make HUNDREDS of annotations to indicate certain locations using .plist database (with title, longitude and latitude).

How can I use UISearchBar to search about these locations then zoom into the location.

thank u